# Navigation bar Title not set and back button not disable in UITableViewControler

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am using UITableViewController in storyboard.

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back2.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(44/255.0f) green:(165/255.0f) blue:(264/255.0f) alpha:(1.0f)]];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"SETTINGS"];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The problem is i want to hide Back button and title are not show in navigation bar. same code works in UIViewcontroller.

Comment: Where exactly did you place this code ? In which method ?

Comment: If you don't find the problem, maybe just use a UIViewController and put a ViewController inside. The changes are minor and the UIViewController will give you more flexibility later (in my experience..)

Comment: I place this code in viewWillApear method.

Answer (score 0):

I created simple scene using storyboard: uinavigation controller -> uiviewcontroller -> uitableviewController.

Code works on both uiviewcontroller and uitableviewController.

So, i suggest you to check the next things:

1. your uitableviewcontroller embeded with uinavigationController;
2. your segue type is Show (e.g. Push) for Xcode 6 or Push for older versions
3. Check simulated metrics -> Top bar for proper value (i recommend Inferred for all navigation chain)

As for title and bar decoration i used this two methods as a category for UIViewController to split decoration logic from title logic

```
-(void)decorateNavigationBarAppearance
{   
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = RGB(255, 255, 255);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [self imageWithColor:RGB(154, 153, 163) size:(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1.0f))];    
}

- (void) setNavigationItemTitle:(NSString *)title
{

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 310, 40)];
    titleLabel.text = title;
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Bold" size:17];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textColor = RGB(255, 255, 255);
    UIView *content = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    [content addSubview:titleLabel];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = content;
}
```

Sure, you can use this snippet for you purpose just modifying decoration params such colour or font name/ size

Hope this helps.